# Order by joined with unpivot table with pagination

Tags: sql-server

I have a 3 tables, I need to apply sorting and pagination.

```
Create Table Interviews(
Id int primary key,
StartDate datetime2,
LocationName varchar(50),
)

Create Table Questions(
Id int primary key,
Title varchar(500)
)

Create Table Answers(
Id int primary key,
AnswerText varchar(500),
QuestionId int,
InterviewId int,
)

ALTER TABLE Answers ADD FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId) REFERENCES Questions(Id);
ALTER TABLE Answers ADD FOREIGN KEY (InterviewId) REFERENCES Interviews(Id);
```

[Tables Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJeVD.png)

[Questions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSWlq.png)

[Interviews Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YhOv.png)

[Answers Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/227G1.png)

I need to sort by (first name, age).

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT a.Id,
           a.AnswerText,
           a.QuestionId,
           a.InterviewId,
           i.LocationName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.AnswerText) AS InterviewOrderNumber --Not correct
    FROM Interviews i
        LEFT JOIN Answers a
            ON i.Id = a.InterviewId
) t
WHERE InterviewOrderNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

[I hope this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2k6l.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with paginated as (
    SELECT a.Id as AnswerId,
           a.AnswerText,
           a.QuestionId,
           a.InterviewId,
           i.LocationName,
           min(case when q.Title = 'First Name' then a.AnswerText end) over (
               partition by i.Id) as Name,
           min(case when q.Title = 'Age' then cast(a.AnswerText as int) end) over (
               partition by i.Id) as Age
    FROM Interviews i
         INNER JOIN Answers a ON i.Id = a.InterviewId
         INNER JOIN Questions q ON q.id = a.QuestionId
)
select *,
    dense_rank() over (order by Name, Age, InterviewId) as InterviewOrderNumber
from paginated;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/LlBpd2x-

Comment: Error thrown: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Ahmad' to data type int.

Comment: I restructured the query. If you see that error again then change to `try_cast()`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly your question

You wanted to be sorted based on first name and age of the questions and then pageing the data based on that sorting

```
;with _listQuestion as(

        select *,case 
                     when Title='FirstName' then 1
                     when Title='age' then 2 
                     else 3 end as InterviewOrderNumber  
        from Questions
)
select *
from (
        select a.*,b.LocationName,c.InterviewOrderNumber,c.Id as iq ,c.Title
        , row_number() OVER (  ORDER BY InterviewOrderNumber ) AS rw
         FROM Answers  a
         inner join Interviews b on a.InterviewId=b.Id
         inner join _listQuestion c on  c.Id=a.QuestionId
 )t
 where t.rw between 1 and 5
```

```
Create Table Interviews(Id int primary key,StartDate datetime2,LocationName varchar(50),)
Create Table Questions(Id int primary key,Title varchar(500))
Create Table Answers(Id int primary key,AnswerText varchar(500),QuestionId int,InterviewId int,)

ALTER TABLE Answers ADD FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId) REFERENCES Questions(Id);
ALTER TABLE Answers ADD FOREIGN KEY (InterviewId) REFERENCES Interviews(Id);

insert into Questions values(1,'firstname' ),(2,'lastname'),(3,'age')
insert into Interviews values(1,'2022-05-01','usa'),( 2,'2023-05-01','uk') ,(3,'2024-05-01','fr')
insert into Answers values(1,'Mohmoud',1,1),(2,'akr',2,1),(3,'27',3,1),(4,'Ahmad',1,2)
insert into Answers values(5,'zen',2,2),(6,'30',3,2),(7,'obai',1,3),(8,'gh',2,3),(9,'27',3,3)
```